# Can I access the form elements of a flash form from qtwebkit?

Tags: flash, qt, npapi, qtwebkit

I have a qtwebkit browser with Mozilla NPAPI plugins from which I access a web page. This page contains flash forms and I need to be able to access and manipulate its elements.

Does anyone knows if this is possible and how?

PS: I don't want to use flash's ExternalInterface

Comment: I'm not too familiar with NPAPI plugins but I have never seen a way besides using ExternalInterface to talk between Flash and non-flash web code (such as JavaScript) on the same page. Out of curiosity why do you not want to use ExternalInterface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to communicate between the browser (or another plugin) and a npapi plugin is through the NPRuntime interface. Flash supports the NPRuntime interface and allows you to expose methods and properties on it using ExternalInterface; in other words, that is your only real option.

You haven't specified why you don't like this option, but it's all you have. it's all there *is*.